# Character bounces when platform goes up and down

Tags: unity, c#

I have **a player character** with a few `2D Colliders` and a `Rigidbody 2D` attached to it.

When sitting on a **platform** the **player character** can **control the platform** via a lever **and move it up and down**.

This is a short video to showcase the mechanic:

https://media.giphy.com/media/lqgvOWkKyS7euwJwLx/giphy.gif

You can notice the character **bouncing** when the platform moves down. The platform movement is done via a Tweening library (DOTween).

How exactly can I make the **player character** to **stick to the platform** instead of bouncing around?

Comment: The platform moves faster than the gravity that is accelerating your character. There are 2 common approaches depending on the setup. When the characte steps on a movement platform: 1 - parent the character to the platform or 2 - add platform movement to the character's own movement.

Comment: "The platform movement is done via a Tweening library (DOTween)" - yes, but how exactly? Via rigidbody or via transform? In Update or FixedUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Nikaas, there are apparently two common approaches to solve this, one by **making the player character a child of the platform** and the other one to **add platform movement to the character's own movement**.

I decided to go with the first approach and it works wonders.

If anyone also encounters this issue, here is my code that should be attached to the platform. The `objectToAttach` gameobject is a reference to the player character. I will not comment it as I believe most of the functions are very self-explanatory.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AttachChildOnTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject objectToAttach;

    public GameObject GetObjectToAttach()
    {
        return objectToAttach;
    }

    public void SetObjectToAttach(GameObject objectToAttach)
    {
        this.objectToAttach = objectToAttach;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            objectToAttach.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            objectToAttach.transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```